# New Server Install Wireless Not working After Reboot

Tags: 14.04, wireless, server

I installed Ubuntu server 14.04.1 on a box with wireless only. Wireless works during the install but doesn't afterwards. Here's some information about it (I've had to write the information down and switch screens to type it, so there may be some typos):

`/etc/network/interfaces`:
        auto lo
        iface lo inet loopback
        (I tried adding iface wlan inet dhcp but it didn't work)

```
wlan0
     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thru:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

---

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
03:00.0 Network contoller Ralink corp RT3090 wireless 802.11 1T/1R PCIe
```

---

```
dmsg -i wl
IPv6:ADDRCONF:(NETDEV_UP):wlan0: link is not ready
```

---

```
ip addr list
wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtn 1500 qdik mg state DOWN group default
```

---

lshw -C network

```
*-network
    description: Wireless interface
    Product: RT3090Wireless 802.11 1T/1R PCIe
    ...
    logical name: wlan0
    ...
    clock 33MHz
    ...
    configuation: broadcase=yes driver=rt2800 pci driver version=3.13.0-32-generic ...

dmesg | grep -i rt2
ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3090 rev 3213 detected rev 0005 detected
ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: selected rate control algorithm 'minstral_ht'
ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_lib_request_firmware: Info loading firmware ''rt2860.bin'
```

This is the second time I installed it. After the first, I installed ubuntu desktop and wireless worked without problems, so I thought I would install server again (which is what I wanted in the first place).

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features

Hi, I had similar problems and changing my security to suit the more stringent 14.04 resolved my issues. My problems related to the use of mac addresses and I would point you to the link above and [Intel Wireless Wifi Link 5100 on Trusty Tahr not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532057/intel-wireless-wifi-link-5100-on-trusty-tahr-not-working/532357#532357)

14.04 forced me rethink my network security (after a few years) and in particular the use of mac addresses as they can be cloned now days.

Below is an extract of the security policy (link at top)

**No Open Ports

Default installations of Ubuntu must have no listening network services after initial install. Exceptions to this rule include network infrastructure services such as the DHCP client and mDNS (Avahi/ZeroConf, see ZeroConfPolicySpec for implementation details and justification). When installing Ubuntu Server, the administrator can, of course, select specific services to install beyond the defaults (e.g. Apache).
Testing for this can be done with netstat -an --inet | grep LISTEN | grep -v 127.0.0.1: on a fresh install.**

I hope this helps with your quest.

regards

Comment: Thanks Rick. My router is set to accept all connections that provide the required key and I did not set it to restrict/accept based on MAC address. Since DHCP is allowed as an exception to the No Open Ports rule it should 'just work'(?). Note that my linux knowledge is not very advanced...

Answer (score 0):

I should clarify my previous post and the use of mac addresses. I was using 'mac add' over the top of wap, and i did the the most obvious first and turned off the filtering, and just had wap still with no joy. That would almost sound like your situation where your hardware is seen, DHCP etc and everything else set to auto. I'm no guru but some of the security mixes (wifi) still use mac addresses as part of the encryption key makeup (highly recommended reading for a drug free way of getting to sleep).

try this one liner which lists the wifi networks available from your machine.

sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

if you can see your router, I would suggest looking at your security arrangements. 
if you get a message that looks like this:-

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

Your wifi is disabled "turned off". Then try this

sudo NetworkManager start

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

Where NetworkManager operates on the service and ifconfig operates on the interface wlanX, ethX

To help you confirm your settings try:-

iwconfig

You can find descriptions of these via the man pages.

Good luck with your diagnosis.